# If cell A1 in sheet 1 equals 'x' like in sheet 2, then display cell B1 from sheet 2 in sheet 1 cell C2

Tags: excel, if-statement

This might be confusing but I'll give this a go.

As in the title of this question, I need to link cells between two sheets. Seems simple enough, but I think in this case I need to include an IF function?

I want cell C2 in sheet 1 to display what is in cell B2 from sheet 2 IF cell A1 in sheet 1 is the same as cell B1.

In other words: I have 2 sheets, on the second page I have months in on row and in the row under I have values for those months. I want to be able to link sheet 1 and 2 so that if I select February in one cell in sheet 1, then the cell under February in sheet 2 (the value) is shown in another cell on sheet 1.

Help please?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not misunderstanding your wish, there is the code below. Please insert it into cell C2 in Sheet1

```
=IF(A1=B1, Sheet2!B2, "")
```

But you did not provide what sheet of cell B1 in pharse

> I want cell C2 in sheet 1 to display what is in cell B2 from sheet 2 IF cell A1 in sheet 1 is the same as cell **B1**

So, I assumed that it is the same as A1 that is Sheet1. If you want to compare with the cell B2 in another sheet please Insert `Sheet2:` before `B1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the relationships are satisfied by:

```
=IF(A1='sheet 2'!B1,'sheet 2'!B2,"")
```

(in Sheet 1!C2) but have assumed that the result should be nothing if Sheet 1!A1 != Sheet 2!B2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for in cell C2 (if you are talking about A1 and B1 being from the same sheet like 1):

```
    =IF(A1=B1,Sheet2!B2)
```

edit: can't read question, only works if A1 and B1 are on same sheet

Comment: Missed that part. Honest mistake :)